# texture cordinate VBO not being updated OpenGL

Tags: opengl, textures, vbo

I'm making a minecraft style game and I decided to add a VBO with the texture atkas coordinates of the vertices but it is appearing all white. However I'm following the same process as another VBO for the block positions which works

the one that works

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,chunk->posOffsetVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(glm::vec3)*65536,NULL,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(2,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,3*sizeof(GLfloat),(GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribDivisor(2,1);
```

then I fill it with glm::vec3s like this

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,adjacentChunks[1][1]->posOffsetVBO);

glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,sizeof(posOffsets),&posOffsets[0]);
```

this is the one with the texture coordinates that doesn't work

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,chunk->texCoordVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(glm::vec2)*36*1000,NULL,GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(1,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,2*sizeof(GLfloat),(GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

then  fill It with 36 glm::vec2s for each block so one per vertex

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,adjacentChunks[1][1]->texCoordVBO);

glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0,sizeof(texCoords),&texCoords[0]);
```

Is there a reason why the texture one doesn't work?

Comment: Are you calling glGenBuffers to create the new buffer object?

Comment: Yes I am at the top

Comment: I meant at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel stupid, after hours of trying to solve this problem I looked in the vertex shader for the umpteenth time and noticed that I was setting the output texture coordinate to itself. Now it works.